# Converting .htaccess to IIS web.config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I am trying to setup url rewrite for IIS server with Plesk control panel. On local environment with Apache, everything works fine. But no luck on IIS with **500 error on all request**.

The below is my htaccess rewrite config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^(en)/rooms/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=room&room_id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^rooms/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=room&room_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried to convert by using an [online tool here](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx) and receive the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule 1Q" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="!(/$|\.)"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="%{REQUEST_URI}/"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 2a" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(en)/rooms/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?lang={R:1}&page=room&room_id={R:2}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 3a" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(en)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?lang={R:1}&page={R:2}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 4a" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(en)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?lang={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 5a" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^rooms/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page=room&room_id={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 6a" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors>
            ...
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is first time I work on IIS and Plesk, so I had no idea about this issue. So please let me know how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try turning off custom errors by updating web.config element `<customErrors mode="Off" />` under `<system.web>` element. This update should display more detailed errors instead of 500 internal server error

Comment: Hi @MohsinMehmood, Thanks for reply but it did not make the error display

Comment: If you remove the `<rewrite>` section from web.config does it resolve the 500 internal server error?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood If I use rules with only one parameter, it works. From 2 params up, it trigger 500 error 